# Bibliography IEEEtran, citation number overlaps other text

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, ieeetran

I am currently using the

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

and create a bibliography with

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

The document has to columns, but in the end in the bibliography, every reference except the first one is shifted to the left. This results, that the number [x] of the citation overlaps with the text (if the citation is on the right column, the number overlaps the text on the left side!). I added a picture.
Someone knows how to fix that problem?

Thank you for your help!

Nate

[image]

Comment: It looks like a problem with the first entry. -- What is the bibtex code for the first entry ?

Comment: I tried to remove the first entry, which is indeed the only one with the correct format. But then the next (new first entry) is correct and the following ones are still wider.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the issue. In the entry (and in the second and some more) I had a _ inside. I had to replace the underscore with a valid symbol (_).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, after removing and re-adding each entry one by one, I discovered it only happened with the @misc tag, around the url attribute. After I added `\usepackage{url}` to my tex file, everything aligned properly. Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: Thanks. Adding \usepackage{url} package solved my problem.